# перемещение stl модели в пространстве

Tags: c#, opengl, dll, stl-file

Необходимо реализовать просмотр и перемещение `stl` модели.

Моя прога после конвертации получает `stl` модель, надо реализовать ее просмотр и изменение положения модели. Допустим есть стол `250мм Х 250мм X 250mm`. При загрузке модели она болтается где-то в пространстве. Нужно поместить ее в начало системы координат, начало системы должно быть в центре `Ox`, `Oy` они находятся внизу. Соответственно `Oz = 0`.

Сама программа является DLL. Работает из-под NX 8.5. Прогу пишу на C#.

Подскажите куда копать, может есть какие-то примеры.

[image: После преобразования]
[[image: До преобразования]

Comment: То есть вам надо избавиться от паразитного поворота и переноса модели?

Comment: Не обязательно такая ситуация получится, вообщем надо в нуле закрепить центр определенной грани модели ну и чтобы вертеть можно было